# How to write recurrence relation for backtracking problem?

Tags: time-complexity, recurrence-relation, divide-and-conquer

I am not able to understand how to write a recurrence relation for [n queen problem](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/n-queen-problem-backtracking-3/). I searched on web and everywhere it was given directly without explaining how can we arrive to that. 
Recurrence relation is for n*n board $T(n)=n*T(n-1)+O(n^2)$ but  think it should be $T(n)=T(n-1)+O(n^2)$ as if we put the queen anywhere in first row, we are left with $(n-1)*(n-1)$ board and it is sub-problem for T(n-1). But how n gets multiplied is not understandable. Can anyone help in explaining such recurrence relation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Recurrence relation is for n*n board $T(n)=n*T(n-1)+O(n^2)$ but  think it should be $T(n)=T(n-1)+O(n^2)$ as if we put the queen **anywhere in first row**, we are left with $(n-1)*(n-1)$ board and it is sub-problem for T(n-1). But how n gets multiplied is not understandable.

How many cells are there in the first row? $n$. That is where the factor $n$ come from.

- We put the Queen in the first cell of the first row. Removing the first row and first column, we then check the remaining $(n-1)*(n-1)$ board.
- We put the Queen in the second cell of the first row. Removing the first row and second column, we then check the remaining $(n-1)*(n-1)$ board.
- $\vdots$
- We put the Queen in the last cell of the first row. Removing the first row and last column, we then check the remaining $(n-1)*(n-1)$ board.